# Neo4j cypher - search for nodes with no path between them

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to find a generic way to search for a node or set of nodes which does not have a link to a another node or set of nodes.
As an example, I was able to find all the nodes of a specific type (e.g. `:Style`) which *are* connected somehow to a specific set of nodes (e.g. `:MetadataRoot`), with the following:

```
match (root:MetadataRoot),
(n:Style),
p=shortestPath((root)-[*]-(n))
return p
```

Using this, I was able to subtract the set of *all* `:Style` nodes from the nodes returned by the above query, but that doesn't seem like the best way to go about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the label of the start nodes you can use the EXISTS function :

```
MATCH (n:Style)
WHERE NOT EXISTS((n)-[]-())
RETURN n
```

If you know the end node :

```
MATCH (n:Style)
WHERE NOT EXISTS ((n)-[*]-(:MetadataRoot))
RETURN n
```

**EDIT :**

Not sure, but regarding the performance issues in your comment, a workaround could be something like this :

```
MATCH p=allShortestPaths((n:Style)-[*]-(:MetadataRoot))
WITH nodes(p) as nodesRelated
MATCH (s:Style) WHERE NOT s IN nodesRelated
```

Comment: Seems to work when the path length is small (on my server, 10 or less). If it tries to find anything bigger, it crashes. The shortestPath algorithm is fast and efficient; I wish there were something similar for cases like this, like hasPathTo() or pathNotExists()

Comment: mmh maybe a workaround could be to match first the nodes that have paths with allShortestPaths then and aggregate them in a collection. After that match all desired nodes that are not in that collection.

Answer (score 0):

This should be way faster and it should need less resources to execute:

````
MATCH (n:Style),
OPTIONAL MATCH p=shortestPath((:MetadataRoot)-[*0..40]-(n))
WITH n, p 
WHERE p IS NULL 
RETURN n ```
````